# How to use @cython decorator to declare np.ndarray type

Tags: python, numpy, cython

I'm having trouble finding any documentation anywhere that specifically addresses this:

The following code:

```
cdef int foo( double data ):
    # ...
    return int( data )
```

can be written as:

```
@cython.returns(cython.int)
@cython.locals(data=cython.double)
def foo(data):
     return int(data)
```

But I am unable to find an equivalent declaration for:

```
cdef foo(np.ndarray[double] data):
```

Using @cython.locals leads to a compilation error.

What's the proper way of decorator declaring a numpy array in cython?

Comment: Could you use memoryviews instead? Those look like they should work (e.g. `@cython.locals(data=cython.double[:])`) and serve basically the same function as an ndarray. (Note - I haven't fully tested this...)

Comment: @DavidW: I had tried that avenue but was unable to make it work. As it stands, the code you wrote doesn't compile for me. (Error compiling Cython file: test.py:31:52: Not a type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be documented anywhere but memoryviews are accepted as a string:

```
@cython.returns(cython.int)
@cython.locals(data="double[:]")
def foo(data):
     return int(data[0])
```

I imagine this works generally, however the challenge with numpy arrays is that you have to `cimport numpy` which I don't think is possible in pure Python code.

Comment: You are correct about the cimport comment. I think the difference between what you proposed here and what you proposed int the comment is that you used a string literal. This indeed makes the difference.

I'm going to mark this as the answer even though it's not exactly the answer, but may very well be as best we can hope.

Comment: Yes, you are right about the difference between this and my earlier comment and that the version in the comment didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following answers in Google Groups:

> Try making mySum a cpdef function and decorating the one in the .pxd
> file with a cython.locals using the numpy array declaration syntax.

[Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/cik0FOZjbj0)

> You can use a .pxd file and the @cython.locals annotation to declare a
> buffer type.

[Google Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/sdoxpqZWjIk)

Comment: Thanks for looking that up. I'm specifically trying to avoid having to use a .pxd file.

If I can't find a solution to the issue, I will end up having to go there, but it's really not a solution per-se.

As it stands, @cython.locals(data=np.ndarray) works, but doesn't work as fast as the cdef method...